# Respond to touches of html elements with wkebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I load an html document from my bundle into WKWebview. In this example the html doc contains two divs, id = red, and id = green. I would like to be able to tap one of the divs and print it's id to the console. My first thought is to translate the div rects into screen rects and listen for touches inside those rects. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WKScriptMessageHandler` to communicate from web content loaded in a `WKWebView` to you native code.

Modify your html file and add `onclick` events to both of your divs:

```
<div id="red" onclick="redClick()"></div>
<div id="green" onclick="greenClick()"></div>
```

you javascript functions will be like this:

```
function redClick() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.message.postMessage("red");
}
function greenClick() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.message.postMessage("green");
}
```

Then add a script message handler in your `WKWebView`, passing you view controller as `WKScriptMessageHandler`:

```
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "message")
```

and implement `WKScriptMessageHandler` in your view controller like this:

```
extension MyViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print(message.body)
    }
}
```